# How to configure Windows XP/windows 7 to support icmpv6 redirection?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, ipv6, redirection, icmp

I construct an icmpv6 redirection packet. When I send it to Linux, it works well. Then I modify its destination ip and mac address and send it to the corresponding windows XP/7 system, but windows XP/7 seems not to be redirected. Do I miss some configuration of windows system?  What can I do to make windows system support icmpv6 redirection? Thank you.

Comment: Please be aware that accepting redirections makes a system vulnerable to someone on the LAN sending false redirects and blackholing or snooping traffic

Comment: You're right. But I want to test if windows system supports icmpv6 redirection. It's a part of my program. So I need windows system handle this packet.@Sander Steffann